# DB2: Split data results into batch of 5000 records

Tags: python, pyspark, db2

I have a query that returns 600k records and I want to split results into 5000 records.

[enter image description here][1]

! [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ebl8Q.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `row_number()` and `mod()`:

```
select
    t.*
    1 + mod(row_number() over(order by line_nu) - 1, 5000) batch
from mytable t
```

Alternatively, if you want to fetch records by chunks of 5000, you can use the row-limiting clause. This gives you the first 5000 records:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
order by line_nu
fetch first 5000 rows only
```

Then you can get the next 5000 rows as follows:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
order by line_nu
offset 5000 rows
fetch next 5000 rows only
```